# in-line 'try' statement in C# possible?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

Is it possible to somehow invoke inline `try` statement in C#?

I'm detecting languages for my website and sometimes, when language is something like `en-GR` on client side for some reason .NET throws exception. So I need to use `try` and also `catch` even though I'm not really catching anything.

It just seems as a total overkill in this situation.

```
// Set allowed languages
string[] allowedLanguages = { "en", "fr", "ru" };

// Get all possible values
var routeLanguage = (filterContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] != null && allowedLanguages.Contains(filterContext.RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString())) ? filterContext.RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString() : null;
var cookieLanguage = (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["lang"] != null && allowedLanguages.Contains(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["lang"].Value)) ? filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["lang"].Value : null;
string clientLanguage = null;
try
{
    clientLanguage = (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages != null) ? new CultureInfo(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages[0]).TwoLetterISOLanguageName : null; // Exception sometimes without `try`
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

### Edit

Exception is not something I can fix since I have no control over what user has in his culture info. .NET just sees en-FR as invalid one.

Comment: what do you mean with inline try?

Comment: What exception is it throwing?

Comment: Nah. You’re approaching this the wrong way. Fix your error instead of trying to silence it!

Comment: "Exception sometimes without `try`" It's not the index out of bounds exception, is it?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight At the sound of it, `CultureNotFoundException`.

Comment: Exception is not something I can fix since I have no control over what user has in his culture info. .NET just sees `en-FR` as invalid one.

Comment: @Steve No, you *can* fix it.

Answer (score 21):

First off, it is always better to figure out how to avoid the exception in the first place. Concentrate on that first. There is some reason why that exception is being thrown, and if you can determine what it is, then don't do that.

To actually answer your question: there is no out-of-the-box "eat all the exceptions in this expression" mechanism, but building your own is straightforward:

```
static T EatExceptions(Func<T> func)
{
  try { return func(); } catch { }
  return default(T);
}
...
clientLanguage = (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages != null) ? 
  EatExceptions(() => new CultureInfo(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages[0]).TwoLetterISOLanguageName) :
  null; }
```

If someone tried to pull shenanigans like that in code I was reviewing then I would... well let's just say that the change would not get checked in. Eating exceptions like this is a very bad idea 99% of the time. Again: **figure out what you are doing wrong and stop doing it**. Don't do something wrong and then handle the failure.

Comment: I completely agree with the fact that you should always avoid the exception as it's not very performant. I had a case where I wanted my application to attempt doing something and if it failed, it didn't really matter as it was a superfluous.

Comment: @DanAtkinson: The issue is not that exceptions are slow. Exceptions are slow in comparison to, say, addition, but that's because addition is *insanely fast*.  You could throw thousands of exceptions a second and not worry about the perf implications.  The issue is that exceptions are *supposed to be exceptional*. A throw is a *non local goto*; it is hard to imagine a more potentially confusing and damaging control flow than that. So it should be limited to only rare, carefully analyzed cases.

Comment: I of course agree with what you're saying. This answer is probably a sticking plaster on a wider problem, and 'covering up' any attempt to deal with it is counter-intuitive. :-)

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried getting rid of the `try/catch` statement completely?

```
string clientLanguage = null;
var userLanguages = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages;
if (userLanguages != null && userLanguages.Length > 0)
{
    var culture = CultureInfo
        .GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
        .FirstOrDefault(
            x => string.Equals(
                x.Name, 
                userLanguages[0].Name, 
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase
            )
        );
    if (culture != null)
    {
        clientLanguage = culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
    }
}
```

Use try/catch only for handling exceptions that are out of your control. As their name suggests exceptions should be used for handling exceptional cases.

In this case you are doing standard parsing so it is much better to do defensive programming instead of trying, throwing, catching, ...

Comment: I think that this exception is pretty much out of control, is it not? (Edited my post)

Comment: Of course that it is not out of control. Look at my code. I am controlling it. The OP was trying to pass the `TwoLetterISOLanguageName` directly to the CultureInfo constructor. Obviously this could throw an exception if the client has passed some invalid language. In my example I am attempting to find the corresponding CultureInfo from the list of all possible values which cannot throw.

Comment: Well, the FirstOrDefault returns a CultureInfo, but you're assigning it to a string. Like the idea though.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, good point, let me fix that. Answer updated.

Comment: if this one is too slow, you can turn it into a `Dictionary<string, CultureInfo>`

Answer (score 7):

```
_.Try(() => __YourStatementHere__ );
```

Using a little helper class like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Other utility functions.
/// </summary>
public static class _ {

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to execute the given action. If it fails, nothing happens.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Try(Action action) {
        try {
            action();
        }
        catch {
        }
    }

}
```

I know, this solution is not optimal either, but up to now the most concise one I could find.

Answer (score 2):

First **try to avoid the exception**. Just because the string comes from a source you don't control, doesn't mean you can't validate it.

If you can't avoid it, you should **catch the specific exception** you expect and encapsulate that logic in a method. Don't catch all exceptions.

For example:

```
public static CultureInfo TryGetCultureByName(string name)
{
   try
   {
     return new CultureInfo(name);
   }
   catch(CultureNotFoundException)//Only catching CultureNotFoundException
   {
     return null;
   }
}
```

That way, if you later discover a better way to handle this specific error, you can easily replace it.

For example you could create a `Dictionary<string, CultureInfo>`, fill it from `CultureInfo.GetCultures()` and use `TryGetValue` to look up a culture without ever throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is the right way to do it. You stated, why you cannot get rid of the exception (and I assume this is the case). So you have to handle it. Alas, C# does not have a try-catch as an expression (not sure how that would work - the catch "clause" would need to return a value).

Alternatively you can build a little helper function that takes a `Func<T>`, invokes it and passes through the value to the caller. If an exception occurres it returns (for example) `default(T)`. That takes away a lot of the clutter and is reusable.

Answer (score 1):

I've built an in-line try catch mechanic that may suit this purpose. I was going for a sort of LINQ-like or Callback function-y syntax. This is done using a couple of wrappers, a TryWrapper and a CatchWrapper so that the dot operators prompt the next steps appropriately, that implicitly cast to type of T.

[image: Example]

You could also do something like

```
Try(() => UpdateSweetGreen("21", SweetGreen))
.Catch(LogToDb(e.Message))
.Catch(LogToFile(e.Message).Finally(ReportNewSweetGreen(SweetGreen);
```

Basically a CatchWrapper extends TryWrapper. So you could catch an exception off of another catch block. In this instance logging a failure of your method to a database, then if that fails to a file, then no matter what reporting the SweetGreen variable to some other component.

#### This all extends from TryWrapper

```
    public class TryWrapper<T>
    {
        protected internal T Result { get; set; } = default(T);

        protected internal Exception Exception { get; set; } = null;

        public static implicit operator T(TryWrapper<T> wrapper)
        {
            return wrapper.Result;
        }

        public static implicit operator Exception(TryWrapper<T> wrapper)
        {
            return wrapper.Exception;
        }
    }
```

#### and CatchWrapper which simply extends TryWrapper and cannot be invoked directly, instead only appearing after a try as you'd expect with standard implementation

```
    public class CatchWrapper<T> : TryWrapper<T>
    {
    }
```

#### Then a series of static extension methods

```
        public static TryWrapper<T> Try<T>(Func<T> func)
        {
            var product = new TryWrapper<T>();

            try
            {
                product.Result = func.Invoke();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                product.Exception = e;
            }

            return product;
        }

        public static TryWrapper<T> Try<T>(Action action)
        {
            var product = new TryWrapper<T>();

            try
            {
                action.Invoke();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                product.Exception = e;
            }

            return product;
        }

        public static CatchWrapper<T> Catch<T>(this TryWrapper<T> wrapper, Action<Exception> response)
        {
            if (wrapper.Exception is null) return wrapper as CatchWrapper<T>;

            response.Invoke(wrapper);
            wrapper.Exception = null;

            return wrapper as CatchWrapper<T>;
        }


        public static TryWrapper<T> Finally<T>(this TryWrapper<T> wrapper, Action<T> response)
        {
            response.Invoke(wrapper);

            return wrapper;
        }

        public static TryWrapper<T> Finally<T>(this TryWrapper<T> wrapper, Func<T> response)
        {
            wrapper.Result = response.Invoke();

            return wrapper;
        }

        public static TryWrapper<T> Finally<T>(this TryWrapper<T> wrapper, Action response)
        {
            response.Invoke();

            return wrapper;
        }
```

Now this does achieve that inline syntax the OP was asking for but I'd hazard to say its a touch less efficient since you could just deal with the exception directly in a standard try-catch. Still kindof cool to be able to specify the return directly before the Try, though this is risky if  defaults to null.

Answer (score 0):

Well, leaving aside the (good) advice about pre-checking, there are several rather mundane/prosaic/obvious ways to do this:

First, you could wrap it in a function.  I assume that this would not be general enough for you.

Or, you could collapse the `catch` branch:

```
try
{
    clientLanguage = (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages != null) ? new CultureInfo(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages[0]).TwoLetterISOLanguageName : null; // Exception sometimes without `try`
} catch (Exception) { }
```

Or, you could just collapse the whole thing to a single line:

```
try { clientLanguage = (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages != null) ? new CultureInfo(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserLanguages[0]).TwoLetterISOLanguageName : null; } catch (Exception) { }
```

Not elegant, but simple, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is one another way:

```
await new @try(async () => { user = await GetItemAsync(userId); })
         .@catch<Exception>(async () => { user = new User(); });
```

I think it's more verbose than the try/catch:

```
try { return await GetItemAsync(userId); } 
catch (Exception ex) { return new User(); }
```

The helper class:

```
public class @try
{
    private Func<Task> func;
    private Action action;

    public @try(Func<Task> func)
    {
        this.func = func;
    }

    public @try(Action action)
    {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public async Task @catch<T>(Func<Task> fallback) where T : Exception
    {
        try
        {
            await func.Invoke();
        }
        catch(T ex)
        {
            await fallback.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public void @catch<T>(Action fallback) where T : Exception
    {
        try
        {
            action.Invoke();
        }
        catch (T ex)
        {
            fallback.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Inspired on @Andy class